# Change table's column color through depending on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 3 columns and want to change it's color to green depending on what I select on my checklist (form).

I want to change in ***GREEN*** the column depending on the city i choose. For example if I choose New York, then column New York become green. Any ideas?

HTML - Table:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr class="head">
        <th></th>
        <th>New York</th>
        <th>Chicago</th>
        <th>San Francisco</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>A Poetic Perspective</th>
        <td>Sat, 4 Feb 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
        <td>Sat, 3 Mar 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
        <td>Sat, 17 Mar 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <th>Walt Whitman at War</th>
        <td>Sat, 7 Apr 2012<br />11am - 1pm</td>
        <td>Sat, 5 May 2012<br />11am - 1pm</td>
        <td>Sat, 19 May 2012<br />11am - 1pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Found Poems &amp; Outsider Poetry</th>
        <td>Sat, 9 Jun 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
        <td>Sat, 7 Jul 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
        <td>Sat, 21 Jul 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <th>Natural Death: An Exploration</th>
        <td>Sat, 4 Aug 2012<br />11am - 4pm</td>
        <td>Sat, 8 Sep 2012<br />11am - 4pm</td>
        <td>Sat, 15 Sep 2012<br />11am - 4pm</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

HTML - Form :

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Register your interest</legend>
        <p><label class="title" for="name">Your name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br />
            <label class="title" for="email">Your email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></p>
            <label class="title" for="persons">Persons:</label>
            <input id="personsId" type="text" name="persons" id="persons"></p>
        <p><label for="location" class="title">Your closest center:</label>
            <select class="target" name="location" id="location">
                 <option id="1" value="ny">New York</option>
                 <option id="2" value="il">Chicago</option>
                 <option id="3" value="ca">San Francisco</option>
            </select></p>
        <span class="title">Are you a member?</span>
        <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="yes" /> Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="no" /> No</label></p>
    </fieldset>
<div class="submit" id="myButton"><input type="button" value="Register" /></div>
</form>
```

Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".target" ).change(function() {
            $("tr:even").css("background-color", "green");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `if else` add a `data-city` attribute to map which value of dropdown corresponds to which column of the table. Add `data-city` to the `th` like this

```
<th data-city="ny">New York</th>
<th data-city="il">Chicago</th>
<th data-city="ca">San Francisco</th>
```

Based on the dropdown value select the th and get its index. Get the entire column (tds) based on that index and change css.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".target" ).change(function() {
    var city = $(this).val(); // <--- the value from drop down
    var index = $('#myTable th[data-city="'+city+'"]').index()+1; 

    $("td").css("background-color", "transparent"); // <--- reset the color to all columns
    $("td:nth-child("+index+")").css("background-color", "green");

  }).change(); // <-- color the column on load 
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/leqinun/1/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: yeap thank you it works great! but i feel so stupid, i would never think of that solution -.-

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please accept answers if you feel your question has been answered.